# php split data from socket_receive at carriage return and then pipe

Tags: php, vb.net

i have somme data coming from php socket_receive function and it;s like this :

```
ZC* |000195000000B5D0|0000|PTv1.11|ZE20S|ProBee-ZE ZR |000195000000920A|A4C0|PTv1.11|ZE20S|ProBee-ZE OK
```

From this i only need the mac addresses witch are like this form:"000195000000B5D0"

- i want to explode the whole message at carriage return \r\n and then for every row to split again at | and insert the address into database row.

i am trying to use this code:

```
<?php
           $out = socket_recv($socket, $buf, 2048, MSG_WAITALL);
            echo "<br>MESAJ=".$buf;
            $row=preg_split('#(\r\n|[\|])#', $buf);
            print_r($row);
?>
```

in vb.net **on a previous desktop application** i was using this code.

```
  Private Sub SalveazaData()
          Dim list As String() = rtbComData.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())

           For Each Row As String In list
        If Not (Row = "AT+DSCAN=10,2" Or Row = "OK" Or Row = "") Then
            Dim s As String() = Split(Row, "|")
            Dim aRow As smdDataDataSet1.smdTableRow = SmdDataDataSet1.smdTable.NewsmdTableRow()
            aRow.Model = "SCL-50"
            aRow.AdresaUnica = s(1)
            aRow.StatusModul = "ACTIVE"

            Try
                SmdDataDataSet1.SearchAdrese.Rows.Add(s(1))
                SmdDataDataSet1.smdTable.Rows.Add(aRow)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Dim u As String
                u = SmdTableTableAdapter.UpdateInactivActiv()
            End Try
        End If
    Next


End Sub
```

Can you please help me with this? thank you

- the data is long with hundreds of addresses but using this code i mannaged to split at carriage return \n\r :

  MESAJ FROM=".$buf;
      $row=explode("\r\n", $buf);
      echo "
  ROW=".$row[0];
      echo "
  ROW=".$row[1];
  ?>

  and i get the message like this:

  1. ROW=ZC* |000195000000B5D0|0000|PTv1.11|ZE20S|ProBee-ZE
  2. ROW=ZR |000195000000920A|A4C0|PTv1.11|ZE20S|ProBee-ZE

  Now i only need to save the |000195000000B5D0|(address) from every row  in database. how can i do that?

Comment: Is there any special reason why you are using PHP & VB.NET? Unless under very specific circumstances, this combination doesn't make too much sense. What is your exact problem? You are basically not asking anything, just putting ideas/codes together without any clear linkage among them.

Comment: i was showing you the vb.net code for another application that split the strings the way i wanted. now i am trying to do the same thing but with php. MY question is: I WANT TO SPLIT THE DATA COMING FROM THE SOCKET_RECEIVE FUNCTION AND SAVE THE ADDRES INTO DATABASE.

Comment: From your shouts/upper caps, it seems that I am the sole responsible for the fact that you are not able to clearly transmit the simple idea "how can I emulate this VB.NET code in PHP?". Sorry about that.

Comment: you misunderstood my upper caps . i was not rude  . just trying to explain from my own words. my updated by you  question still stands. ! how can I emulate the VB.NET code in PHP? .pls help me if you can.

Comment: OK. If you have already all what is required in place and only want to extract specific bits, you should focus your question on this exact point and forget about all the rest. That is: you have text of the format ROW=ZC* |000195000000B5D0|0000|PTv1.11|ZE20S|ProBee-ZE and you want to extract 000195000000B5D0?. You can do it by relying on PHP explode (as you are doing with \r\n, but with "|") and loop through the resulting array until finding what you want (or take always the given position, that is: the second one; does all the information shows this exact same structure?)...

Comment: In fact this is exactly what you are doing in your VB.NET code (the VB.NET equivalence of explode is Split). You should understand both languages when doing this kind of conversions/adaptations. In the future, please, don't create this kind of chaotic situations where everyone loses (= you don't get help & downvotes + helpers losing lots of time just by trying to understand what you are asking + SO & future readers don't get anything from here). Think carefully about the problem and be as specific as possible; don't just throw things here and expect someone to solve everything for you.

Comment: the information shows in same structure. if i split all the string at " |"  i get : ARRAY[0],[1],[2].....etc  where the first array i need is  array[1] ( 000195000000B5D0) but what about the next address i need to insert into database? if you  have an example just to start with it i would be most grateful

Comment: ok! next time i will pay attention on what i am asking.

Comment: Next addresses? I will tell exactly what the VB.NET code (-> you should know this perfectly yourself). It takes a string (rtbComData.Text) and splits it on account of new lines by generating the array of strings list (i.e., it includes one line per position: list(0) is line 1, list(1) line 2 and so on). Then it iterates through each of these lines and confirms that the format is right (cannot be empty "AT+DSCAN=10,2"  or "OK"). Then splits each of these valid lines on account of | (as suggested), takes the 2nd position (index 1, as suggested) and adds it to SmdDataDataSet1.SearchAdrese.Rows...

Comment: ... your PHP code starts from a somehow different approach (but presumably delivering equivalent results) by relying on Regex (split) rather than on explode (= the closest equivalent to the original VB.NET Split). Now you should set a loop through the resulting lines/array items (as in VB.NET), confirm that they are valid (as in VB.NET), explode each valid one on account of | (split in VB.NET) and store the second position/index 1 in the database (as in VB.NET). You are not only asking very badly, but also about something which is very basic (= offtopic here). My help ends here.

Comment: thank you for your help. using your help i managed to answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

i used this code to answer my question

```
// connect to server
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to IP\n");

//send data to connected socket
 socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
 echo "<br>MESAJ TO :".$message;

 // get server response
$out='';
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec"=>10, "usec"=>0));


    $out = socket_recv($socket, $buf, 2048, MSG_WAITALL);
    echo "<br>MESAJ FROM=".$buf;
    $row=explode("\r\n", $buf);
    echo "<br>ROW=".$row[0];
    echo "<br>ROW=".$row[1];
    foreach ($row as &$s) {
        $s = explode("|",$s);
    echo $s[0];
    echo $s[1];
    echo $s[2];
    $adresaUnica=$s[1];
        if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO `griddata`(`adresaUnica`, `status`, `model`) VALUES ('$adresaUnica','Activ','SCL-50')"))
{
}

            }


    socket_close($socket);
```

}
?>